# Homework: Prove or disprove: (5n)!=O(n!^5)

Tags: time-complexity, computer-science, asymptotic-complexity

I have this question in my h.w:

Prove or disprove: (5n)!=O(n!^5).

I don't know how to approach this (of course I know the O notation definition but I don't have a clue how to solve it).. any help please?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we have to use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) here, which gives the following approximations:

[image]
[image]

Since it is known that:

[image]

We have:

[image]

If you need a more detailed proof, you can indeed use the [Big O formal definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition), still with Stirling's approximation, to obtain this result.